# Windows multiple forms app design

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, forms

I am asked to develop a windows form application. this app will have 4 sessions in sequence for users to complete their task. Should I create this 4 sessions into different forms or what other options do I have?

Comment: Sorry did you mean "sections" instead of "sessions"? otherwise I don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using Wizard. Which can be implemented with tab controls.

Comment: Or with panels that you hide and show.

Comment: Is there a wizard included in WinForms, or are 3rd party controls the only option?